# Buscar nombres de variables PHP en consulta MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, regex

Estoy intentado buscar variables php en una cadena de caracteres almacenada en una base de datos MySql.
Necesito hacer la búsqueda mediante regexp en la consulta MySql. Tengo la expresión regular `(?<![\w\d])$ec_der(?![\w\d])` que me funciona en php pero no sé como hacer el equivalente para MySql.

Si busca en el texto `($x+(-$ec_izq - $ec_der)*$ec) * ($z+($des_tra - 5))` funciona y encuentra `$ec_der`. Gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Revisa los ejemplos de sintaxis [REGEXP](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/regexp.html#operator_regexp) en
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/regexp.html#regexp-syntax

Para el caso puntual, puedes usar la siguiente (no es exactamente igual, pero aisla la variable $ec_der. Puedes revisar la sintaxis para agregar adicional lo que necesites

```
SELECT "($x+(-$ec_izq - $ec_der)*$ec) * ($z+($des_tra - 5))" REGEXP "[^A-Za-z0-9_]\\$ec_der[^A-Za-z0-9_]"
```

`[^A-Za-z0-9]` equivaldría a ![\w\d]. Existen tambien una alternativa con aliases que sería `[^[:alnum:]]`.

**EDIT**

Para el caso de buscar la expresion incluso en el inicio o final del texto deberia ser

```
SELECT "$ec_der ($x+(-$ec_izq - $ec_de1r)*$ec) * ($z+($des_tra - 5))" REGEXP "[^A-Za-z0-9_]?\\$ec_der[^A-Za-z0-9_]?"
```

Aqui agregando `?` en la expresion indica que el elemento es *opcional*.

Comment: Efectivamente para ese caso concreto me vale, pero por ejemplo si $ec_der está al principio de la cadena o al final no me la encuentra. También si busco con su expresión SELECT "($x+(-$ec_izq - $ec_der)*$az) * ($z+($des_tra - 5))" REGEXP "[^A-Za-z0-9]\$ec[^A-Za-z0-9]"; el resultado es TRUE cuando $ec no está en la cadena. Es decir lo que necesito saber es si el nombre de una variable PHP concreta (no que contenga) está almacenado en un campo de texto de la base de datos.

Comment: Añadí un ejemplo para los casos al inicio/final. La expresion de debe completar con `_` que tambien es un caracter valido para variables.

Comment: Yo he probado añadiendo el caracter _ y además la opción de que sea el principio o final de cadena.
En un principio parece que me funciona.
(^|[^A-Za-z0-9_])\\$med_bas([^A-Za-z0-9_]|$)